# Continuous columns sum based on another column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like below

| AppName | Start | Finish | Totaltime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:30:25 | 2021-02-28 7:31:25 | 1 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:31:26 | 2021-02-28 7:33:25 | 2 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:33:27 | 2021-02-28 7:35:25 | 2 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:35:28 | 2021-02-28 7:37:25 | 2 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:37:29 | 2021-02-28 7:39:25 | 2 |
| Windows Explorer | 2021-02-28 7:39:30 | 2021-02-28 7:41:25 | 2 |
| Windows Explorer | 2021-02-28 7:41:31 | 2021-02-28 7:43:25 | 2 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:43:32 | 2021-02-28 7:45:25 | 2 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:45:33 | 2021-02-28 7:47:25 | 2 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:47:34 | 2021-02-28 7:49:25 | 2 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:49:35 | 2021-02-28 7:51:25 | 2 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:51:36 | 2021-02-28 7:53:25 | 2 |
| Microsoft Excel | 2021-02-28 7:53:37 | 2021-02-28 7:55:25 | 2 |

and need the coninuoues column Totaltime sum based on App name

output something like this

| AppName | Start | Finish | Totaltime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:30:25 | 2021-02-28 7:37:25 | 7 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:37:29 | 2021-02-28 7:39:25 | 2 |
| Windows Explorer | 2021-02-28 7:39:30 | 2021-02-28 7:43:25 | 4 |
| MS Word | 2021-02-28 7:43:32 | 2021-02-28 7:47:25 | 4 |
| Google Chrome | 2021-02-28 7:47:34 | 2021-02-28 7:53:25 | 6 |
| Microsoft Excel | 2021-02-28 7:53:37 | 2021-02-28 7:55:25 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps and islands problem.  You don't care about the time gaps in the table, so you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select appname, min(start), max(finish), sum(time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by start) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by appname order by start) as seqnum_a
      from t
     ) t
group by appname, (seqnum - seqnum_a)
```